# How to make query MongoDB NodeJS for select top 5 data major?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In DB i have data like this:

```
{
"name": "Hendry",
"major": "IT"
},
{
"name": "Adam",
"major": "Architect"
}
...
```

My question is, how to select data user, which is top 5 major the most.

Example return:

```
{
"IT": "10" //10 User,
"Architect": "8" 
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can try the aggregation grouping, to start with - using the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). Then you can use the sorting and limiting stages.

Comment: @prasad_ can you show me the example? Thank you

Comment: The link in my previous comment is a good starting point. There are bunch of examples on the Stack Overflow and other sites - you have to do some simple searching.